# Yii framework dialog box

Tags: php

On a manage admin page we have a link. When we click this link, a dialog box should open on the same page. The dialog box contains a form so that the user can fill out the form and save the data.

How can I do this using Yii?

Comment: You need to start adding much, much more context and detail and actual error messages to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this type of question is very subjective in nature. But still, I will try to answer.

In the "Manage Admin" page, when the user clicks the (one) link present, then a dialog box opens up with a contact form. This can be done using any one of the many available [jQuery Modal Box plugins](http://choosedaily.com/1178/15-jquery-popup-modal-dialog-plugins-tutorials/). You need to make sure that you please search for a specific sort of plugin, which supports `HTML` `INPUT` markup tags, that are required for any form.

Next is submitting the form & saving the contact form data. So submitting the form is very easy, since you will require the `FORM` tag with the attribute "`method`" (whose value should be "`post`" & not "`get`"). If "`get`" is used, then all the data will be passed to the server as query string format making the data as open to be viewed by all. Instead if "`post`" is used, then data will be submitted without being visible to anyone. Also this form should be submitted, using the "`jQuery`'s" "`submit()`" method, or any other suitable ways (like using the `INPUT` tag).

Regarding saving the data into the database, it will be best if you can read the [`Yii`](http://www.yiiframework.com/) article series written by [Larry Ullman](http://www.larryullman.com/series/learning-the-yii-framework/). Specifically you will require the following articles amongst the series available:-

- [Configuring Yii](http://www.larryullman.com/2009/11/03/configuring-yii/)
- [Defining Databases for the Yii Application](http://www.larryullman.com/2009/11/05/creating-models-views-and-controllers-in-yii/)
- [Creating Models, Views, and Controllers in Yii](http://www.larryullman.com/2009/11/07/creating-models-views-and-controllers-in-yii-2/)

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

complete solution of your question is here

for example we have a model 'client' we want to add new client using a link button on admin.hp page
STEP 1:
Change actioncreate in client.php model and replace with this code.

```
 public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new client;




    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['client']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['client'];


        if($model->save())
        {
            if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
            {
                echo CJSON::encode(array(
                    'status'=>'success', 
                    'div'=>"Client successfully added"
                    ));
                exit;               
            }
            else
                $this->redirect(array('view','id'=>$model->id));
        }
    }

    if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)
    {
        echo CJSON::encode(array(
            'status'=>'failure', 
            'div'=>$this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model), true)));

        exit;               
    }
    else
        $this->render('create',array('model'=>$model,));
}
```

STEP 2:

replace all code of admin.php with the following ,but be careful i have used model client..you should use your own model.
    /
    / @var $model client */

```
/*
$this->breadcrumbs=array(
'Clients'=>array('index'),
'Manage',
);
*/
$this->menu=array(
array('label'=>'List client', 'url'=>array('index')),
//array('label'=>'Create client', 'url'=>array('create')),
);
?>
 <h1>Manage Clients</h1>
<div>

<?php echo CHtml::link('Add Client ', "",  // the link for open  dialog
array(
    'style'=>'cursor: pointer; font-size:20px; text-decoration: underline;',
    'onclick'=>"{addclient(); $('#dialogclient').dialog('open');}"));
  ?>
   </div><!-- add-form -->
   <?php
    $this->beginWidget('zii.widgets.jui.CJuiDialog', array( // the dialog
    'id'=>'dialogclient',
    'options'=>array(
    'title'=>'Create Client ',
    'autoOpen'=>false,
    'modal'=>true,
    'width'=>550,
    'height'=>470,
      ),
      )); 
     ?>
    <div class="divForForm"></div>
    <?php $this->endWidget();?>
    <?php  $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
      'id'=>'client-grid',
      'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
      //'filter'=>$model,
      'columns'=>array(
    'id',
    'Client Name',
    'first_name',
    'last_name',
    'email_address',
    'created_date',
    array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
    ),
    ),
      )); 
     ?>



   <script type="text/javascript">
    // here is the magic
   function addclient()
   {
     <?php echo CHtml::ajax(array(
      'url'=>array('client/create'),
        'data'=> "js:$(this).serialize()",
        'type'=>'post',
        'dataType'=>'json',
        'success'=>"function(data)
        {
            if (data.status == 'failure')
            {
                $('#dialogclient div.divForForm').html(data.div);
                      // Here is the trick: on submit-> once again this function!
                $('#dialogclient div.divForForm form').submit(addclient);
            }
            else
            {
                $('#dialogclient div.divForForm').html(data.div);
                setTimeout(\"$('#dialogclient').dialog('close') \",3000);
            }

        } ",
        ))
   ?>;
       return false; 

     } 

      </script>
```

If face any problem .plz reply